# Parse, How to send array entries as multiple PFObjects, Create a new row for each array object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as the backend for my app. My app will be used in the field where service will nonexistent or spotty at best so I need to store information offline. I currently save data for the user in a plist in the background (Title, location coordinates, notes, additional data). Since Parse's current iOS offline saving is fairly poor (From what I've read), I was hoping to get around it by creating an array or dictionary from the plist and upload that to Parse by giving it an array once the user is back in cell range.

As it occurs now, when I upload the array, it simply puts the entire contents of the array in a single cell in the database. Is there a way to parse the array and create a new row for each entry/object in the array?

I may have overlooked a better way to do this. If someone has a suggestion I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I iterated through the array using a for loop and added each index as a separate object.